# embed google map with a route between two marks using latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, routes

I know how to create a link to google maps with a route between 2 marks using lat and long like this

```
<a href='https://maps.google.com?saddr=lat,lon&daddr=lat,lon'target='_blank'></a>
```

The question is how to embed this map using these coordinates into my website as an iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)

> https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
>     ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
>     &origin=Oslo+Norway
>     &destination=Telemark+Norway
>     &avoid=tolls|highways
>
> The following URL parameters are required:
>
> **origin** defines the starting point from which to display directions. The value can be either a place name, address or place ID. The string should be URL-escaped, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to City+Hall,New+York,NY. (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.) Place IDs should be prefixed with place_id:.
>   **destination** defines the end point of the directions.

**example:**

```
origin=40.7127837,-74.0059413  (New York, NY)
destination=42.3600825,-71.05888 (Boston, MA)

iframe code:
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=40.7127837,-74.0059413&destination=42.3600825,-71.05888&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_directions.html)

Comment: No.  But that is a different question.